# Typescript: Infer existence of a property by using a helper function

Tags: typescript

Given the following interfaces and type:

```js
interface A {
  foo: string;
}

interface B {
  bar: string;
}

type AorB = A | B;
```

The following works:

```js
function getFooOrBar(obj: AorB): string {
  if ('foo' in obj) {
    return obj.foo;
  }
  return obj.bar
}
```

But the following won't:

```js
function getFooOrBar(obj: AorB): string {
  if (isA(obj)) {
    return obj.foo;
  }
  return obj.bar;
}

function isA(obj: AorB): boolean{
  return 'foo' in obj;
}
```

because I guess the compiler is not smart enough to infer the property's existence based on the implementation of a function.

Is there a way to extract `'foo' in obj` into a helper function so the compiler can still infer the existence of `obj.foo`?

Comment: `isA` should be a typeguard `function isA(obj: AorB): obj is A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [typeguards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```js
interface A {
    foo: string;
}

interface B {
    bar: string;
}

type AorB = A | B;


function isA(obj: AorB): obj is A { // change is here
    return 'foo' in obj;
}

function getFooOrBar2(obj: AorB): string {
    if (isA(obj)) {
        return obj.foo; // ok
    }
    return obj.bar; // ok
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mx3a7N)